# Rtf to Html removes the html tables

Tags: c#, html, rtf

I have the following code to convert rtf text to html:

```
private string RtfToHtml(string rtf)
{
    IRtfDocument rtfDocument = RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc(rtf);
    RtfHtmlConverter htmlConverter = new RtfHtmlConverter(rtfDocument);
    return htmlConverter.Convert();
}
```

This is taken from [this library on code project.](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/recipes/rtfconverter.aspx)

If my rtf text contains Html tables such as:

```
{\*\htmltag96 <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plain \f0\fs24 \htmlrtf0
```

They are removed in the resultant html text. How can I preserve these?

However, any text or details in the tables remains, this results in the html text not being formatted correctly because of the lack of tables.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Convert-RTF-file-to-HTML-4d3b70e6 try this out

Comment: @AshishBahl No any HTML tables are removed

Comment: can you share your code snippet?

Comment: @AshishBahl For the SautinSoft code? I just downloaded the test project from your link and replaced the rtf file with my own. And then had to download the dll from their site.

Answer (score 3):

Near the end of Introduction of the article from where you took the library :

> There is no special support for the following RTF layout elements:
>
> - **Tables**
> - Lists
> - Automatic numbering
> - All features which require knowledge of how Microsoft Word might mean it ...

This project might be helpful:
[rtf2html](https://github.com/lvu/rtf2html)

It claims to process tables better than any other existing converter. However it is written in C++ and from what I can tell you are working with C#.

That being the case, you might want to take a look at some of the source code in the project in order to help you rewrite the same thing in C#.

As far as existing C# libraries that can properly process tables I don't think one currently exists.

Comment: Note that this converter is incredibly old and also doesn't support features such as images and hyperlinks. Also this is little more than a link only answer and would have been better posting as a comment like the previous commenter on the question has done.

Comment: Also note that this doesn't seem to work, please don't post a suggestion but an actual answer.